# Directed weighted multigraph isomorphism algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, graph-isomorphism

Are there known algorithms for the isomorphism problem for directed weighted multigraphs? If not, could one be created simply by adapting existing algorithms for graphs or digraphs, or is it entirely non-obvious?

Comment: Your problem is likely GI-complete. I suggest taking a look at some examples of reducing fancy variants of graph isomorphism to the classical setting.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So is there no "direct" result on this particular problem, but one is supposed to be able to figure out an adaptation by himself?

Comment: You can adapt the Weisfeiler-Lehman approach.